# Insert data from STDIN to specific position of string

Tags: linux, unix

**Case**: I wanna insert some data from a file to specific position of the string.

**Example**:

```
cat users.log | mysql -h localhost -u mysql -e 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE ${USERS_IDS}'
```

I want to replace ${USERS_IDS} string to the data from the file
I'm sure this case is very popular, but I did not find a suitable solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert the contents of a file in a specific position of a string you use the facilities of your shell.

For example, [Bash has the `$(<` filename`)` construction](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#expansion):

```
mysql -h localhost -u mysql -e 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE '"$(< users.log)"
```

If the data to be inserted needs to be editted a little, you have the `$(`command`)` construction:

```
mysql -h localhost -u mysql -e 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE '"$(< users.log sed -e 's/.../.../')"
```

Whether the file substitution or the command substitution are to be enclosed in doublequotes or not depends on the specific use case.

And, if the intended use is really to feed values in a MySQL command, beware of [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).